# preg_replace_callback occurrences of match unless a backslash exists 0-20 chars ahead

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

For a long time I've been using preg_replace_callback to replace any occurrence of a reference ID into a link that opens  the reference.

For example, "BIZ1234" would be replaced with Name title (pseudo code)

All good.

But now I need to **not** do the replacing **if** a backslash precedes the match.

For example, if the "BIZ1234" is used in a folder path: \drive_C\BIZ1234

For this I've tried a lot of regular expressions, and almost got what I needed, but my skills in regular expressions just aren't enough.

Current regular expression:

```
/BIZ(\d+)/i
```

Attempts of excluding occurrences where a backslash precedes the match:

```
/[^\\\\]BIZ(\d+)/i
```

This works if the backslash is right infront of BIZ.
I realize I have to set some kind of limit as to how far back the backslash can be. So I try:

```
/[^\\\\](.{0,20})BIZ(\d+)/i
```

This replaces too much and doesn't care about the backslash.

I've read and read, but just can't grasp these regular expressions. Help! :-)

EDIT / ADDED:

I'm using the following as a test string (the following is **1** string):

```
<p>This should become a link BIZ1234</p>
<p>this/here/should/too BIZ1234</p>
<p>but\this\here\shouldn't BIZ1234</p>
```

Currently, using this regular expression:

```
/^([^\\\]+)BIZ(\d+)/
```

Replaces nothing in the above string.

Comment: `[^\\\\]` doesn't make much sense:  `[^...]` means any character *not* one of `...`, so no need to repeat the backslash.  You may want to look into [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: @biffen, it does makes sense, in the context of a PHP string to pass to Preg_replace_callback: Since the backslash is a special character in regex, you have to escape it – makes \\ to mean _one_ backslash in regex. It is also a special character in PHP strings, so it has to be escaped in there as well – and we have two backslashes here that are meant to be content inside the string, and escaping each makes you end up with _four_ backslashes.

Comment: @CBroe I assumed the regexen showed were the *un-escaped* ones, since  there's a `\d` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [lookbehind alternative, could use \K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#k) to reset the beginning of the match:

```
$pattern = '/>[^<\\\]*\KBIZ(\d+)/';
```

This would replace only from where you put the `\K`.

So for example match `>` followed by `[^<\\\]*` any amount of characters that are NOT `<` or backslash, followed by `BIZ` but reset and start replace just before `BIZ`.

[Example at eval.in](https://eval.in/126206)